# cucumber: how to run specific scenario from a feature file

Tags: java, cucumber

I have multiple scenarios listed in a feature file and I need to run only a single failing scenario (for debugging purposes).

I have mentioned @tag before the scenario but while in Test Runner file when given this tag it is running entire feature file. Please help me out how to put it correctly.

TEST Runner file -

```
tags={"@Islamic_User_check"},
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Update: there is now a tags options

```
cucumber --tags @tagname
```

In maven:

```
 mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @tagname"
```

(and in Windows powershell escape the -D with a backtick)

```
 mvn test `-Dcucumber.options="--tags @tagname"
```

Comment: The option is now: `mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tagname"`

Comment: This Dário command work's perfect for me.

Answer (score 35):

If you want to run a specific scenario using cucumber you need to provide the line number the scenario starts on like:

```
cucumber features/test.feature:7
```

if you use the @ feature it should point to a txt file where the line number is still given.

Source: https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/cli/run-specific-scenarios

Hope this helps

Comment: This works from Maven as well, something like: `mvn -D cucumber.options="src/test/resources/features/test.feature:7" verify`.

Comment: Although this works, it is a very brittle approach, as any line shifting modification in the feature file will break this. Using tags, is a much more reliable approach.

Comment: Agree that it's brittle but sometimes I find myself not wanting to add a tag to a scenario just so that I can run it for debug purposes.  Also, the line number doesn't have to be where the scenario starts - it can point to any step in the scenario and it will run the whole scenario.

Answer (score 16):

If you use **IntelliJ** then I suggest installing the Cucumber for Java plugin.

[image]

Then you can right-click on the `Test` annotation in the `feature` file and run that single test scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the `--name REGEXP` command line argument to run only the scenarios that match the regular expression REGEXP:

```
cucumber --name "Islamic_User_check"
```

Comment: does this also works without annotation the scenario?

Comment: I think so, but I don't have my current environment set up for cucumber so I can't test it out to verify.